# Digital control implementation in MCU

Tags: control-engineering

I have implemented a PI compensator for an integrator plant through floating point variables and everything works fine. The design intent is tracking filter and it does not track well the input signal. In simulation, everything works well. What could be the problem and what is the workaround?

Comment: Welcome to engineering stackexchange. Can you please share with us details of your implementation?

Comment: If your plant model is an integrator, the controller shouldn't contian an integrator. The right control solution should be P or PD.

Comment: @CoffeeDrivenOrganism an integrator would be indicated for such a plant if there's some offset that needs to be compensated for -- I've certainly had to do that in motion-control systems with torquer motors.

Comment: @TimWescott, yes if there is an integrator in the closed loop, the system will have no steady-state error. But your plant is an integrator, hence the integral action is already in the system and therefore you don't need to add another integrator in the control. In fact adding the second integrator in the controller destabilizes the system and therefore it doesn't track the input well.

Comment: Well I am implementing an angle tracking observer that has PI compensator cascaded with  an integrator.. Inputs are sine/cos waves from encoders and I am using this algorithm to estimate the velocity and position.

Comment: @gari I think you should elaborate your question with graphs, code and equations, since it's not clear to me what your goal and problems are. The question states compensator and tracking while in your previous comment you're talking about an observer.

Comment: Ok, I will clarify. The problem is about resolver to digital conversion using classical ATO method. ATO receives three inputs Viz.  excitation signal , sine and cosine. ATO is simply a PI compensator cascaded with integrator forming a type2 loop, which is suitable for tracking. To start with I used matalb and PSIM to simulate my algorithm and everything works fine in continuous and discrete domain. When I translate this to a code , I experience a tracking lag which is quite mysterious. I use encoder as  standard reference for comparison

Comment: Did you implement your controller with a fixed sample rate and a small time delay?

Comment: Yes I did, Samples rate is 2500 Hz ( for 50Hz input) . Program within ISR